# WPF client Application is stopped during of the debugging when i try to watch value of the any variable

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, debugging

I have a problem with debugging in MS VS 2010. There was a WPF project writing in VS 2008 which i have converted to VS 2010. Presently when i try to debug a client of this project and watch value of any variable, my Application always closes and then debuging stops.

Others projects writting with the help VS 2010 are debugged without any problems

Comment: check VS addons/extensions. also worth checking any probable recursion in the code(less likely to affect)

Comment: But this project work when i debug it in MVS 2008. Therefore there is no any problem in my code... What are addons and extension, where do i find them?

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228765(v=vs.100).aspx & http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd293640(v=vs.100), this may help you if there is any issue because of them

Comment: There is no any add-in, but there was one extension which i have just disabled, but there is no any result...

Comment: I am clueless at the moment, as last resort you may try debugging the concerned project on a different pc. if the problem is resolved then probably you may need to re-install your installation of VS otherwise I don't see any solution at the moment.

Comment: Maybe this will help you, when i try to inspect variable (clicking symbol plus "+") in the field where value of the vfriable must be a message appears like this "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to renable function evaluation"

Comment: "different pc" My colleague has the same problem on his computer...

Comment: Timeout issue is very generic, it is difficult to make a guess from it. BTW is it possible for you to send a working sample of the code/project? may I give it a try. you may upload to any file sharing service.

Comment: I would like to give this project, but one is not mine and is very, very big, not big... but enormous!

Comment: all I can suggest is to clean the solution. perform a full rebuild. see if there is any missing dependencies or other conflicts. also may try replacing the dependencies with the appropriate versions if needed. I think that's all I can say.

Comment: I have already tried to clean this solution and performed a full rebuild but this have not helped me... The Solution builds and works, thus there is no any messing dependencies or not? By the way, i have noticed that sometimes the solution closes during debugging only when i try to inspect array or object with a big hierarchy, but others variable are opened

Comment: it that is the case there might be a possibility of cyclic reference, which leads to timeout or crash in the concerned version of VS.